# Is it a good practice to refer a view that is defined later in android layout file

Tags: android, layout

The question comes from the below UI requirement, a text with a rectangle background.

[image]

I implemented this with below layout, and you can find that `dumpTv1` is defined later, but I can refer it earlier. Is it a common operation as I always define firstly then use it? And this code can just run well. BTW is there a better way for this requirement?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/dumpTv1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/dumpTv1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FAFA98"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dumpTv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="推荐课程"
        android:textColor="#FF333333"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should use `layout_alignStart="@+id/dumpTv1"` in that case, but it should work just fine. Generally, you just add a + if the view is declared later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not directly a problem you only have to provide

```
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dumpTv1"
```

If you have the textview above in the layout file you can also skip the "+" like

```
android:layout_alignStart="@id/dumpTv1"
```

But no worry android studio will complain if it is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem. It won't create any problem as long as you don't refer to a view that is not associated to your layout anyhow or you don't refer to a view outside your viewgroup.